# How to start function, only after file has been selected by the user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple GUI that after pressing upload button, selecting files and uploading them, will run another function. Problem is, no matter what I try, it either brakes the GUI completely or simply doesn't work.

my current code looks like this

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

def populate(frame):
    # for image in filename():
    #         image = Image.open(image)
    #         photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS))

    #         label = Label(top_left, image=photo)
    #         label.image = photo
    #         label.pack()

    for row in range(100):
        tk.Label(frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", 
                  relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
        t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
        tk.Label(frame, text=t).grid(row=row, column=1)

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    
def uploadAction(event=None):
     filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose files')
     print('Selected:', filename)
     return filename
    
def uploadButton():
    UploadButton = Button(root, text='Select image(s)', command=uploadAction)
    UploadButton.place(relx = 0.40, rely = 0.9)# 100,y = 260)
    #UploadButton.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Deasease detector')
root.minsize(600,600)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=5, background="green")
frame = tk.Frame(canvas, background="blue")
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((4,4), window=frame, anchor="nw")

frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))

uploadButton()

populate(frame)# ????????????????????????????????????????

    
root.mainloop()
```

populate(frame) is the function I'd like to call after the files have been submitted, however I have been unsuccessful so far.

I tried using after() function and lambda to call two functions with button press, however neither has worked so far.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just call `populateFrame(...)` inside `uploadAction()`.  However, `populateFrame()` has nothing related to the selected files.

Comment: @acw1668 The idea is to use the selected files to do some manipulation and show results of that manipulation in that frame. Is this possible?

Comment: Then you can simply call `populateFrame()` inside `uploadAction()` and pass the selected files as an argument of `populateFrame()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `populate()` inside `uploadAction()`, but you need to pass the selected files to `populate()`:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

...

def populate(frame, filenames):
    # do whatever you want on filenames
    # below will show all the selected images in the frame
    for row, fname in enumerate(filenames):
        image = Image.open(fname)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        label = tk.Label(frame, image=photo)
        label.grid(row=row, column=0)
        label.photo = photo

def uploadAction(event=None):
     filenames = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose files')
     print('Selected:', filenames)
     if filenames:
        populate(frame, filenames) # call populate() on filenames
     return filenames
```

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't work as I am getting exactly same error I was getting with my previous code
  File "<string>", line 35, in uploadAction
NameError: name 'filenames' is not defined
if statement in uploadAction doesnt have filenames and throws an error.
starting to think I might need threading to do this...

Comment: @GregorySky `filenames` is a local variable inside `uploadAction()`, so it should not has the issue you stated.  Did you change `filename` to `filenames` in the line `filenames = filedialog.openfilenames(...)`?

Comment: I am clearly an idiot. Thank you so much for all your help!